# what's the correct way to have template haskell wrap a function with source information (e.g. line number)

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

Suppose I start with a function

```
fromJust Nothing = error "fromJust got Nothing!"
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

Then, I want to add source information via Template Haskell for better error messages. Let's imagine that I could add an extra parameter to the function

```
fromJust' loc Nothing = error $ "fromJust got Nothing at " ++ (loc_filename loc)
fromJust' loc (Just x) = x
```

and then have some `fromJust` macro that I could use in source code like,

```
x = $fromJust $ Map.lookup k m
```

#### hack

I did manage to hack it, by using quasiquotes and lifting the string of the source filename. It seems that `Loc` doesn't have a Lift instance. Is there a better way?

```
fromJustErr' l (Nothing) =
    error $ printf "[internal] fromJust error\
        \\n    (in file %s)" l
fromJustErr' l (Just x) = x
fromJustErr = do
    l <- location
    let fn = loc_filename l
        fnl :: Q Exp = TH.lift fn
    [| fromJustErr' $fnl |]
```

Thanks!

(I know it's nicer to `fmap` stuff via the `Maybe` functor than use `fromJust`, but I need to hack sometimes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt at making this pattern somewhat more reusable.

The key idea is to pass a customized `error` to our function which will include the location in the error message. You'd use it like this:

```
fromJust' :: (String -> a) -> Maybe a -> a
fromJust' error Nothing = error "fromJust got Nothing!"
fromJust' error (Just x) = x

fromJust :: Q Exp
fromJust = withLocatedError [| fromJust' |]
```

Using this function is similar to your original approach:

```
main = print (1 + $fromJust Nothing)
```

Now, for the Template Haskell that makes this work:

```
withLocatedError :: Q Exp -> Q Exp
withLocatedError f = do
    let error = locatedError =<< location
    appE f error

locatedError :: Loc -> Q Exp
locatedError loc = do
    let postfix = " at " ++ formatLoc loc
    [| \msg -> error (msg ++ $(litE $ stringL postfix)) |]

formatLoc :: Loc -> String
formatLoc loc = let file = loc_filename loc
                    (line, col) = loc_start loc
                in concat [file, ":", show line, ":", show col]
```

`locatedError` produces the customized `error` function, given a location. `withLocatedError` feeds this to `fromJust'` to hook everything together. `formatLoc` just formats the location nicely into a string.

Running this gives us the result we wanted:

```
FromJustTest: fromJust got Nothing! at FromJustTest.hs:5:19
```

Comment: You know, I seem to recall seeing [a package doing something similar with TH and error messages](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/placeholders)...

Answer (score 1):

How about making a new error function?

```
locError :: Q Exp
locError = do
    loc <- location
    msgName <- newName "msg"
    eError <- [|error|]
    eCat <- [|(++)|]
    let
        locStr = loc_filename loc
        locLit = LitE (StringL locStr)
        pat    = VarP msgName
        body   = AppE eError locLit
    return $ LamE [pat] body
```

Then use it like

```
foo :: Int
foo = $(locError) "This is an error"
```

(It's incomplete -- doesn't give the message, just the file, but you get the idea)

EDIT

On re-reading your question, I realize this isn't what you're trying to do. It's an interesting idea -- you're trying to get *caller* location information -- sort of like a stack trace but only one layer deep. I have no idea how that would work.

Though I guess you could use the same trick of `locError` to make `locFromJust` -- but you wanted a general way, which this isn't.